# Binary Searchable Problem Statement Giving TLE error

Tags: java

##### Problem Statement

Given an unsorted array of N integers, your task is to find all the elements which can be found through a traditional binary search. An element is binary searchable if it can be found for any value of pivot.
For example:- Suppose the given array is [3, 2, 5, 4, 6, 7] and target = 6, we can find 6 because we will reach 6 at last. But for the target = 4, it will not be possible when the pivot is 5.

###### Input

The first line of input contains a single integer N. The next line of input contains N space separated integers depicting the array.

###### Constraints

1 <= N <= 100000
1 <= Arr[i] <= 1000000

###### Output

Print the number of elements that can be found using the traditional binary search.

Example
Sample Input

```
3
3 2 1
```

Sample Output

```
0
```

Sample Input

```
6
3 2 5 4 6 7
```

Sample Output

```
2
```

---

```
class Main {
    // public static long binarySearchable(int[] Arr, int n) {
    //     // int n = nums.length;
    //     // long count = 0;

    //     // int[] maxLeft = new int[n];
    //     // maxLeft[0] = nums[0];
    //     // for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    //     //     maxLeft[i] = Math.max(maxLeft[i - 1], nums[i]);
    //     // }

    //     // int minRight = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    //     // for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    //     //     minRight = Math.min(minRight, nums[i]);
    //     //     if (nums[i] <= minRight && nums[i] >= maxLeft[i]) {
    //     //         count++;
    //     //     }
    //     // }

    //     // return count;
    //     if(n <= 1) return n;
    //     int[] leftmax = new int[n];
    //     int[] rightmin = new int[n];
    //     int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE, max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    //     for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    //         min = Math.min(min, Arr[n-1-i]);
    //         rightmin[n-i-1] = min;
    //         max = Math.max(max, Arr[i]);
    //         leftmax[i] = max;
    //     }
    //     int count = 0;
    //     for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    //         if(leftmax[i] == Arr[i] && rightmin[i] == Arr[i]) count++;
    //     }
    //     return count;
    // }

    // static int getBinarySearchableNumbers(int[] arr) {
    //     int[] largest = new int[arr.length], smallest = new int[arr.length];
    //     int binarySearchableCount = 0;

    //     if (arr.length == 0 || arr.length ==1) {
    //         return arr.length;
    //     }
    //     for (int i=0;i< arr.length;i++) {
    //         if (i == 0) {
    //             largest[i] = arr[i];
    //             continue;
    //         }

    //         if (arr[i] >= largest[i-1]) {
    //             largest[i] = arr[i];
    //         } else {
    //             largest[i] = largest[i-1];
    //         }
    //     }

    //     for (int i=arr.length-1;i >= 0;i--) {
    //         if (i == arr.length-1) {
    //             smallest[i] = arr[i];
    //             continue;
    //         }

    //         if (arr[i] <= smallest[i+1]) {
    //             smallest[i] = arr[i];
    //         } else {
    //             smallest[i] = smallest[i+1];
    //         }
    //     }

    //     for (int i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
    //         if (arr[i] == smallest[i] && arr[i] == largest[i]) {
    //             binarySearchableCount++;
    //         }
    //     }

    //     return binarySearchableCount;
    // }
    public static int howMany(int[] sequence) {
        
        int count = 0;
        int temp;
        for(int i=0;i<sequence.length;i++) {
            temp = 0;
            for(int j=0;j<i;j++) {
                
                if(sequence[j]>sequence[i]) {
                        temp = 1;
                        break;
                    }
            }
            for(int k=i+1;k<sequence.length;k++) {
                if(sequence[k]<sequence[i]) {
                    temp = 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(temp==0)
            count++;
        }
        return count;
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int N = sc.nextInt();
        int[] arr = new int[N];
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            arr[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println(howMany(arr));
    }
```

The first commented code giving Wrong output and second code giving TLE what is wrong in this program... Please Suggest me

Comment: it seems expected result for `3 2 1` should be `1` since we always may find `2` using binary search, and for `3 2 5 4 6 7` expected result should be `4`

Comment: Please don't tag with `dsa` (read its description)